# botframework channelData for kik results in error: 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: botframework, kik

I'm using the Microsoft Botframework and the node.js version of botbuilder.  My bot can send messages to kik (and other services) using the shared message fields - the ones that the botconnector allows for all messages.

However, when I try to use channelData fields for kik, I get a 400 (Bad Request) error message.  I have already adapted my message to use the tip from: 
[Bot Connector: Sending custom message to Kik results in 400 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335198/bot-connector-sending-custom-message-to-kik-results-in-400-error)
but I'm still missing something.

Thanks for any help on mapping the message properly for kik.

Code that results in the 400 error:

        `session.send({
            type: "Message",
            to: { "channelId":"kik", "address": session.message.from.address},
            from: { "channelId":"kik", "address": session.message.to.address}, 
            replyToMessageId: session.message.id,
            conversationId: session.message.conversationId,
            channelConversationId: session.message.channelConversationId,
            channelMessageId: session.message.channelMessageId, 
            channelData:
            {
              "messages": [
                {
                    "chatId": session.message.channelConversationId,
                    "type": "text",
                    "to": session.message.from.name,
                    "text": "test text",
                    "noForward": true
                }
              ]
            }
        });`

I've also tried sending only the channelData portion, but that also results in the 400 error:

            `channelData:
            {
              "messages": [
                {
                    "chatId": session.message.channelConversationId,
                    "type": "text",
                    "to": session.message.from.name,
                    "text": "test text",
                    "noForward": true
                }
              ]
            }`

Answer (score 0):

I believe your data is malformed.  Kik expects text content as "**body**" not "**text**".  Try:

```
"messages": [
            {
                "chatId": session.message.channelConversationId,
                "type": "text",
                "to": session.message.from.name,
                "body": "test text",
                "noForward": true
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Lars.  That didn't seem to do it. I tried with both sets of data (channelData only and with more of the message information as in my original post).  Am still getting: "Service Error:Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request)."

Comment: Double check that you don't have your 'from' and 'to' addresses reversed.  The 400 is coming directly from Kik.

Comment: I think I have the "from" and "to" correct - am using the "from" from the message sent by the user as the address the bot sends "to".  I can send non-channel-data messages to Kik without a problem, just haven't figured out how to format/send messages that use the Kik specific channel data fields.